# Convert text to xml

Tags: c#, xml

I want to convert a tab delimited text file to a XML file. I was able to do it with a single character delimiter. But how do i extend it to tabs? I am coding in C# and using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: How did you do it with a single character delimiter?

Comment: Yes, if you still get these - please share how to convert tab delimited text to xml ...

Answer (score 1):

A tab is a single character, written as `'\t'`. Try adapting your existing solution to use that. If that doesn't work, post more details about your approach and the problems you encountered.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want to split your lines using the tab char? In that case, use the method you already have and use `\t` for splitting.

Comment: See answer by Blair Conrad :-) -- beat me to it

Answer (score 1):

Are the tabs an `\t` symbol? Then the task is, basically, the same.
If by tabs you mean multiple spaces, you might want to delete the extra spaces. A simple way is to use a regex:

```
  string input = "This is   text with   far  too   much   " + 
                 "whitespace.";
  string pattern = "\\s+";
  string replacement = " ";
  Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
  string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);
```